# What happens when BFT is breached through collusion? Can Block.one add objective enforcement?

Tags: bft

My first question is what happens after 6 nodes collude in order to transmit dishonest transactions? Can that be undone?

> "What’s most important in this context isn’t the minimum number of
>   honest nodes needed in order to enforce BFT, but the minimum number of
>   dishonest nodes needed to negate BFT.
>
> By raising it to 15/21, a bad actor now only needs to collude with
>   28.24% (6/21) of the 21 block producers in order for its cartel to control the entirety of the network."

My second question, does Block one currently plan to address this by adding additional objective enforcement of BFT by slashing deposits or similar? And if not, why?

Comment: I do not think there is such a thing as "dishonest transaction", as nodes would not be able to sign transactions as they do not hold private keys. What they can do, however, is to stop the network down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes 15 BPs to collude in order for the transactions to be made irreversible on the chain. I believe in the case of 6 colluding malicious BPs, there would be a fork until one of the 6 BPs was voted out (presumably the other BPs would be voted out too shortly after).

In the case where 15 BPs actually colluded, then everyone would stop using that chain and move onto another EOSIO chain.